# C# error: not all code paths return a value. Casting a string to a float

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, methods, error-handling, floating-point

I am writing a program that reads a data set from a file and casts it to variables. I ran into an issue with my casting method (which casts a string in an array to a float) because I keep getting a "not all code paths return a value" error. Does anyone know how I can get around this?

here is my code:

```
    public float Get_Value(string line)
    {
        float dataValue;
        // Searching for block containing data value
        string[] lineset = splitline(line);
        string valueString = lineset[2];
        try
        {
            dataValue = float.Parse(valueString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("invalid data");
            dataValue = -9999999999;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm just wondering, why the downvotes? There are people with different skill levels and may miss simple things once in a while...

Answer (score 6):

You forgot:

```
return dataValue;
```

At the bottom of your function.

Comment: thanks. I'm silly for missing that gonna delete the post now.

Comment: @user2561937, don't feel bad.  Keep the post - we all make mistakes.  Future visitors may go "oh, doh!  of course!" and find your post helpful :)